# DbEntityValidationException when using EF System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddOrUpdate in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I'm getting DbEntityValidationException when I'm saving entity via Entity Framework System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddOrUpdate.

Here is first screenshot:
[image]

I'm also using AutoMapper to map Domain entities to Dbo entities.
[image]

I have 2 tables Content & ContentType and ContentType is Domain enum:
[image]
[image]

I want just add item into Content table, but it looks like AddOrUpdate is trying add also item into ContentType and I don't know how to exclude it and just tell that it is FK.

If I use only this Mapping

```
config.CreateMap<Content, ContentDbo>();
```

or this

```
config.CreateMap<Content, ContentDbo>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.ContentTypeId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (int)src.ContentType));
```

I'll get this error:
[image]

So I need to add also this mapping:

```
config.CreateMap<ContentType, ContentTypeDbo>();
```

If I use all mappings I still have this problem.
[image]

Automapper is initialized from Global.asax.cs
[image]

Here you can download also my test app -> [DOWNLOAD >>](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzIDgdwGDsdHX1ZPblZsV18xZjA/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: Take care with the AddOrUpdate method: http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/